# JPA one-to-one insert how to do it properly with eclipselink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am trying to do simple one-to-one mapping with JPA and EclipseLink.

I have the following DB structure in PostgreSQL

```
CREATE TABLE public.employee (
  id SERIAL,
  firstname VARCHAR(20),
  lastname VARCHAR(20),
  CONSTRAINT employee_pkey PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
CREATE TABLE public.employee_info (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  info TEXT DEFAULT ''::text NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT employee_info_pkey PRIMARY KEY(id),
  CONSTRAINT employee_info_fk FOREIGN KEY (id)
);
```

and I am trying to reflect this as the following code:

Employee:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Integer id;
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "firstname")
  private String firstname;
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "lastname")
  private String lastname;
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "employee")
  private EmployeeInfo employeeInfo;
...
}
```

and employee_info

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_info")
public class EmployeeInfo implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)  
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Integer id;
  @Column(name = "info")
  private String info;
  @OneToOne
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
  private Employee employee;
...
}
```

Now I am trying to insert the data:

```
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    Employee emp = new Employee();
    emp.setFirstname("FirstName");
    emp.setLastname("LastName");
    EmployeeInfo ei = new EmployeeInfo();
    ei.setInfo("some info");
    emp.setEmployeeInfo(ei);
    em.persist(emp);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
    emf.close();
```

and get the error, since JPA is generating the INSERT query without specifying the id for the second table

```
[EL Info]: 2015-02-28 14:15:31.741--ServerSession(1440332016)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
[EL Info]: connection: 2015-02-28 14:15:31.902--ServerSession(1440332016)--file:/D:/PROJEKTY/JAVA/JPATest3/build/classes/_JPATest3PU login successful
[EL Warning]: 2015-02-28 14:15:31.963--UnitOfWork(2115597658)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (null, some info).
Error Code: 0
Call: INSERT INTO employee_info (info) VALUES (?)
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(jpatest3.EmployeeInfo[ id=null ])
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (null, some info).
Error Code: 0
Call: INSERT INTO employee_info (info) VALUES (?)
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(jpatest3.EmployeeInfo[ id=null ])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:157)
    at jpatest3.JPATest3.main(JPATest3.java:32)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (null, some info).
Error Code: 0
Call: INSERT INTO employee_info (info) VALUES (?)
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(jpatest3.EmployeeInfo[ id=null ])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.processExceptionForCommError(DatabaseAccessor.java:1611)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:898)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:962)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:631)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2002)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.insertObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1786)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1737)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitNewObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:4207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1441)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1531)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitRootUnitOfWork(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1169)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:132)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (null, some info).
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2157)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1886)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:555)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:417)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:890)
    ... 33 more
Java Result: 1
```

Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix the code or data structure to have it working fine with JPA / Eclipselink?

Thank you

**EDIT 1:**
The code below works, but is this the way it should be done?

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
emp.setFirstname("FirstName");
emp.setLastname("LastName");

em.persist(emp);
em.flush();

EmployeeInfo ei = new EmployeeInfo(emp.getId(), "some info");
em.persist(ei);
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")

public class Employee implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Integer id;
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "firstname")
  private String firstname;
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "lastname")
  private String lastname;
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "employee")
  private EmployeeInfo employeeInfo;

@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_info")

public class EmployeeInfo implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Integer id;
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "info")
  private String info;
  @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  @OneToOne(optional = false)
  private Employee employee;
```

---

**EDIT 2:**
After some time I found out how to achieve what I wanted.
I asked wrong questions. It was not about one-to-one mapping.
It was as simple as **@SecondaryTable** annotation. With @SecondaryTable(s) annotation one entity can be spread around two or more tables and this is what I wanted to achieve

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
@SecondaryTable(name = "employee_info")

public class Employee implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  @Column(table = "employee_info")
  private String longName;
```

....

```
Employee e = new Employee();

e.setName("name");
e.setLongName("long name");

em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(e);

em.getTransaction().commit();
emf.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You mapped the relation as managed by the EmployeeInfo, it means that you also have to set the employee on the newly created EmployeeInfo object as JPA will not do it for you. As it is now, JPA tries to save the employeeinfo without the parent object (and you get your null key, but that is not all).

The employinfo primary key is the primary key of the employee so it cannot be generated as you declared @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY), but it has to adopt the primary key of its parent empolyee  object.

You need to use @Id or @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn on you @OneToOne mapping in EmployeeInfo to inform JPA that the key should be derived from the parent, there is explanation of it here:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Primary_Keys_through_OneToOne_and_ManyToOne_Relationships

Finally, it will be better if you change your ID generation on employee from the Identity to Table. That way the JPA "knows" the key before the inset and can setup the keys on both objects, otherwise it has to insert first and retrieve the primary key set.

So for examplee:

```
EmployeeInfo {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
...
  @OneToOne
  @Id
  @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
  private Employee employee;
}

Employee emp = new Employee();
emp.setFirstname("FirstName");
emp.setLastname("LastName");

EmployeeInfo ei = new EmployeeInfo("some info");
ei.setEmploy(emp);
emp.setEmployeeInfo(ei);

em.persist(emp);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. indeed the @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) was wrong in the EmployeeInfo. But although I fix this I still have errors. I'd like to stay with database generated identities. Does it mean that I have to manually flush the employee and then pass its id to the employeeInfo? This to me breaks the whole idea. Am I missing something?

Comment: I added the code that is working fine, when I manually flush employee, but is this the right way?

Comment: Have you read the link? Add @Id to your OneToOne mapping, remove generated value, set employee on info and info on employee object. Persist the Employee (you already have cascade.all on your parent). I edited the answer with some code.

Comment: Thank you for explanation and the code. In the meantime I realized how it should be done. All the problems came from misunderstanding on my site. I thought that I should map EmployeInfo in the Employee class and persist emp, not ei. But it is actually the opposite. I am reading the "Apress Pro JPA 2 Mastering" and many things gets explained and more clear now, also thanks to your help which I appreciate very much.

Comment: I am still curious how to build a model, where employee data is spread in 3 db tables. I think that current model would not work. Could you advice how to act in that case? We would have employee, employeeInfo1, employeeInfo2, all with shared primary key.

Comment: I found it finally. It is just about @SecondaryTable annotation :-)