# update one table in @onetoone mapping in hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

jpa class is this:

```
public class JpaAlertConfiguration{
...
   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinColumn(name = "alert_type_id", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private JpaAlertType         alertType;
}
```

Create Entity is called from this class method.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public JpaAlertConfiguration createEntity(JpaAlertConfiguration entity) throws Exception
{
    getAuthorizer().checkCreate(ENTITY_NAME);
    validateFields(entity);

    getAuthorizer().checkAccountAccess(entity.getAccount().getId(), null);
    entity = attachAssociatedEntities(entity);
    // entity.setStatusColumns(new StatusColumns().setStatus(ResourceStatus.Disabled));
    entity = super.createEntity(entity);
    entity = transformResult(entity);
    return entity;
}
```

I made sure that till this line is called, `entity = super.createEntity(entity);`, JpaAlertType id value is populated, which is nothing but "alert_type_id" of alertConfig table.

I am getting exception:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "alert_type_id" violates not-null constraint
>     Detail: Failing row contains (3, Speed Alert, Speeding Alert, 5, t, null, Enabled, 0, 2016-09-06 17:56:30.556+05:30, 2016-09-06 17:56:30.58+05:30, 2016-09-06 17:56:30.556+05:30, null, f, f).

Please suggest

Comment: What is `JpaAlertType` and what is vakue of `entity.alertType`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolve:
Actually here in my scenario I was calling generic createEntity method. Not sure but I just removed all the complicate annotation from 
alertType variable in JPAAlertConfiguration class

```
 @OneToOne(optional = false)
 @JoinColumn(name = "alert_type_id")
 private JpaAlertType         alertType;
```

and it worked. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing JPA persisting order, see the link below about [JPA one-to-one insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782324/jpa-one-to-one-insert-how-to-do-it-properly-with-eclipselink), i hope this could help.

Comment: Thanks Kamal. That Link I checked before posting my question. Didn't really help. But I managed to resolve it somehow. Posted the answer also.